# Consulta sobre Getters & Setters

Tags: java

Es más bien para tener una idea de que forma es mejor para desarrollar un proyecto.

Creo la clase y pongo los *getters* y *setters* y luego **métodos** , o sería mejor poner dentro de los *getters* y *setters* métodos con condiciones?

```
public  Vehiculo(String matricula,int puntos){
    this.matricula=matricula;
    this.puntos=puntos;
}

public String getMatricula() {
    if(matricula.lenght > 6){
           matricula = "1234tr";
           return matricula;
       }
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public int getPuntos() {

    return puntos;
}

public void setPuntos(int puntos) {
    this.puntos = puntos;
}
```

O ponerlo en un metodo sencillamente.

Answer (score 0):

Los getters y setters son métodos de "acceso" cuyo objetivo principal es obtener (getter) o configurar (setter) valores de un atributo del objeto, estos métodos deben ser configurados como "public" ya que puedes obtener o asignar un valor desde otra clase de tu proyecto.

Lo común es realizar las "operaciones" en otros métodos y usar los métodos getter y setter únicamente para obtener o asignar el valor a un atributo.

```
public String getMatricula() { 
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
   this.matricula = matricula;
}
```

Pero en el caso que expones, **si el valor de `matricula` siempre estara determinado en tu proyecto por la operación que realizas dentro del getter `getMatricula()` puedes sin duda optar por usar este método que contiene la operación**.

```
public String getMatricula() {
    if(matricula.length > 6){
           matricula = "1234tr";
           return matricula;
       }
    return matricula;
}
```

Comment: En el caso de que la matrícula deba asumir **siempre** el valor `1234tr` cuando la extensión de la misma sea mayor a `6` lo más lógico sería evaluar eso en el constructor de la clase y/o en el setter. Si esa es la norma general en el contexto, como bien dices, lo cual veo poco probable en un escenario real. Yo pondría un *getter*  dedicado para este caso y metería ahí la lógica que aparece ahora en `getMatricula()`

Answer (score 0):

> Encapsulamiento y abstraccion.
>
> Los atributos de la clase deben ser de tipo private o protected para que el cliente 
>   que use tu clase no tenga acceso a los mismos.

```
public class Vehiculo{
 private String matricula;
 private int puntos;

public  Vehiculo(String matricula,int puntos){
 this.matricula=matricula;
 this.puntos=puntos;
 }
```

}

El cliente puede tener acceso a los atributos por los getters y los setters, por lo que si un cliente usa tu clase para un hacer un programa, y a vos se te ocurrio otra forma de obtener la matricula o cambia la estructura de la matricula, vos podes cambiarla y al cliente no le modifica nada. Ya que el entro en getMatricula(), la clase debe ser programada como una caja negra, el cliente sabe lo que hace la clase pero no como lo hace.